# Jquery animate same css attribute with delay

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, delay

I want to animate css attribute margin top twice, first until it's going to be '10' and then I want to start second animation until is going to reach '0'. My code almost works but the second animation doesn't start immediately and the second animation keep repeating 4 times.

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#holder").offset().top + $("#holder").outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {

   $('#holder').animate({'margin-top': '10'}, 300).delay(300).animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 900);
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding">
            <div class="ourStoryBox">
                <div id="holder">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
 #holder {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 299px;
  height: 299px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/blurredBoxBig.png");
  }
```

Comment: Post the HTML markup as well.

Comment: Try to dequeue it: `$('#holder').dequeue()...`  or `$('#holder').stop()`. BTW, you should debounce the scroll handler, using a timeout, search for it on this site/google